# Shortcut to open command prompt with preloaded command

Tags: windows, batch-file, ffmpeg

I use `FFMPEG` to convert MP4s to WEBMs. This involves me constantly copying over my preferred script into the command prompt every single time. Is there a way to open a commant prompt with a certain command already set up and ready to go without executing the commmand immediately so that it is still editable? Many times I need to change parameters of the script to match the specific file I will be converting...so simply having a pre-loaded script that runs by itself doesn't make sense.

Tried making a CMD shortcut but couldn't find a way to do this without automatically running the command. Tried making a batch file, got the script to copy in, but it wasn't editable.

Here is the *FFMPEG* script I use: `ffmpeg -i "in.mp4" -b:v 3000k -b:a 128k -threads 6 out.webm`

Answer (score 1):

open notepad, save the content below into it and save it as `my_ffmpeg_script.cmd` and simply double click it:

```
@echo off
:start
cls
set /p "input=Filename to convert?: "
set /p "output=Output filename?: "
set /p "rate1=a rate? (i.e 3000): "
set /p "rate2=b rate? (i.e 128): "
set /p "threads=Threads? (i.e 6): "

ffmpeg -i "%input%" -b:v %rate1%k -b:a %rate2%k -threads %threads% %output%
set /p "next=Would you like to convert another?(y/n): "
if /i "%next%"=="n" exit
if /i "%next%"=="y" goto :start
```

It will prompt you for your input, output, rates and threads, then do the conversion and ask if you want to do another file, if yes, start prompt again, if no, it will exit the script.

Obviously you can set some of the values as default values in the line and not prompt for them, if they will never change. This is simply to show you how to do something like this.